# Deserialize xml string to json and then json to object

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize xml string to json and then json to the object. 
I'm trying this:

converting xml string to xmlDocument

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
```

xmlstring is formated
then serializing xml into json

```
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.Indented, true);
```

and then trying to deserialize json string into my object

in that case value of variable "json" looks like

```
 {
   "$type": "ESBSerializerTest.MyClass1, ESBSerializerTest",
   "strI1": "strI1",
   "intI1": "2",
   "Interface2s": {
     "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ESBSerializerTest.IInterface2, ESBSerializerTest]], mscorlib",
"$values": [
  {
    "$type": "ESBSerializerTest.MyClass2, ESBSerializerTest",
     "intI2": {
      "@xmlns": "",
      "#text": "111"
    }
  },
  {
    "$type": "ESBSerializerTest.MyClass2, ESBSerializerTest",
    "intI2": {
      "@xmlns": "",
      "#text": "222"
    }
  },
  {
    "$type": "ESBSerializerTest.MyClass2, ESBSerializerTest",
    "intI2": {
      "@xmlns": "",
      "#text": "333"
    }
  }
]}
```

and json can't deserialize values of my list because they should look like this:

```
{
    "$type": "ESBSerializerTest.MyClass2, ESBSerializerTest",
    "intI2": "111"
  },
```

Deserealizing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, ContractResolver = new ESBDynamicContractResolver(_kernel) };

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass1>(json, settings);

 public class MyClass1 : IInterface1
{

    public string strI1 { get; set; }
    public int intI1 { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass2> Interface2s { get; set; }
    public int intC1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you deserialize it? Also your JSON is invalid.

Comment: maybe its invalid because I missed same brackets

Comment: Also add your `TType` model class

Comment: Do you really need to go from XML > JSON > Object? XML deserialization itself gives you a lot of control over the process.

Comment: Main goal to make serializer (to xml and json). Give to that serializer an Interface ans serialize only those properties, that included in interface. Deserealize must work in that way to.

Comment: I don't know where to make xml serializer\deserializer if I give him property with IInterface type to change it on depending class, I know how, bou don't know where)